# Is the following proof for the derivative of a product true?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, proof-verification

The following is a rigorous proof:

Let $s$ and $t$ be functions of $x$ and let them be defined for all real numbers, and let $y$ be their product so that $y=st$. Next, let $x$ be increased by $\delta x$, to cause corresponding increases in $y, s$ and $t$. Therefore:

$y$ becomes $y+\delta y$

$s$ becomes $s+\delta s$

$t$ becomes $t+\delta t$

then:

$y+\delta y = (s+\delta s)(t + \delta t)$

$\delta y = (st+s\delta t + t\delta s +\delta t \delta s) - st$

$\delta y = s\delta t + t \delta s +\delta t\delta s$

then divide through by the initial change in $x$

$\displaystyle \frac{\delta y}{\delta x} = s\frac{\delta t}{\delta x} + t\frac{\delta s}{\delta x} + \delta t\frac{\delta s}{\delta x}$

then take the limit:

$\displaystyle {\lim_{\delta x \to 0}} \frac{\delta y}{\delta x} = {\lim_{\delta x \to 0}} s\frac{\delta t}{\delta x} + {\lim_{\delta x \to 0}} t\frac{\delta s}{\delta x} + {\lim_{\delta x \to 0}} \delta t\frac{\delta s}{\delta x}$ (according to the summation property of limits)

now here's where my question lies: we know that since $t$ is a continuous function of $x$, as $\delta x \to 0$, $\delta t \to 0$. This being said, when the limit of $\displaystyle \delta t \frac{\delta s}{\delta x}$ is taken, the term will approach $0$, meaning there is no point in including it in the equation in the first place, meaning that:

$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = s\frac{dt}{dx} + t\frac{ds}{dx}$

But, what if, instead of writing $\displaystyle \delta t \frac{\delta s}{\delta x}$, we had written $\displaystyle \frac{\delta t\delta s}{\delta x}$, and then took the limit? Wouldn't this have changed the result of the equation?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is very nice intuition but I would not say it is fully rigorous. In order to prove something rigorously, you need to use definitions (in this case, the limit definition of the derivative and the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit) or perhaps previously proven results.

Comment: You could just as well write that last bit as $$\frac{\delta t}{\delta x}\frac{\delta s}{\delta x}\delta x$$. Since the first two fractions converge, and $\delta x\to 0$ the whole term converges to zero. It's not clear why rewriting it as $\frac{\delta t\delta s}{\delta x}$ changes anything.